# How to group Ember data records?

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli, ember-1

I have a route that looks like this:

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    orders: this.store.find('order')
  });
},
```

Which returns all orders. An order has the following fields: `id`, `user_id` and `product_id`.

My API returns:

```
[
    { id: 1, user_id: 1, product_id:1 },
    { id: 2, user_id: 1, product_id:1 },
    { id: 3, user_id: 1, product_id:2 }
]
```

Which translates to, the same user has 3 orders. 2 apples (which cost $1 each) and an orange (which costs $1).

In my `.hbs` template. I'd like to display something along the lines of:

```
2 apples: $2
1 orange: $1
```

How do I go about grouping orders? Unfortunately, the Ember.Enumerable class (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html) goes as far as `sortBy`. No `groupBy`.

Should I be looking at `reduce` or something else?

Comment: I need a js fiddle :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following discussion - http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-enumerable-no-group-by/3594

Basically, you would do something like

```
groupedResults: function () {
  var result = [];

  this.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
    var hasType = result.findBy('type', item.get('type'));

    if(!hasType) {
     result.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({
        type: item.get('type'),
        contents: []
     }));
    }

    result.findBy('type', item.get('type')).get('contents').pushObject(item);
   });

   return result;
}.property('content.[]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this answer and have a lot of success with using the [ember-group-by](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-group-by) addon.

The `groupedResults` example above written with the addon would look like this:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import groupBy from 'ember-group-by';

export default Controller.extend({
  groupedResults: groupBy('model', 'type')
});
```

This is the more modern way to define "properties" ([computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties/)) and is nice and clean